# Alignment issue in counter. (days hour to top instead of bottom)

Tags: html, css

Hello i have this html and i want to align `day, hour, minute, seconds` to `top` instead of `bottom` and i want to adjust distance between `time`. 
i tried margin-top, padding nothing is working.

```css
#timer3 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Lobster;
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  color:
}

.label_timer3 {
  display: block;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<b id="timer3">
  <div id="days3">
    7 : <span class="label_timer3"> Daypp</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hours3"> 
    6 : <span class="label_timer3"> Hour</span>
  </div>
  <div id="minutes3"> 
    25 : <span class="label_timer3"> Minute</span>
  </div>
  <div id="seconds3"> 
    18 <span class="label_timer3"> Second</span>
  </div>
 </b>
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Also `b` should not contain `div` elements - it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sonamona here you go,

```css
#timer3 {
  display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
  font-family: Lobster;
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 20px;
  }

.label_timer3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 8px;
}

#timer3 div span{
 margin:20px 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="timer3">
  <div id="days3">
   <span class="label_timer3"> Day</span> 7 : 
  </div>
  <div id="hours3"> 
  <span class="label_timer3"> Hour</span>  6 : 
  </div>
  <div id="minutes3"> 
   <span class="label_timer3"> Minute</span> 25 : 
  </div>
  <div id="seconds3"> 
   <span class="label_timer3"> Second</span> 18 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Also, @Paulie_D is correct divs in divs are ok but not within bold tags .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul>
  <li>DAYS |</li>
    <li>HOURS |</li>
  <li>MINUTES |</li>
  <li>SECONDS</li>
</ul>
<p id="time">00:00:00:00</p>
  <button id="start">START</button>
    <button id="stop">STOP</button>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00b8e6;
  background-color: #000;
}

.container {
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align:center;
}
ul {margin-left:-40px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
li {
  display:inline;
}
p {
  font-size: 60px;
}
button {
  background-color: #008080;
  border:none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#ccffff;
}

button:hover, button:focus {
  background-color: #00b8e6;
  color:#fff;
}
```